# iostream.h error when compiling a C code

Tags: c

I want to compile this code with GCC, using terminal :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char card_name[3];
    puts("Enter the card_name:");
    scanf("%2s", card_name);
    int val = 0;
    if (card_name[0] == 'K') {
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'Q') {
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'J') {
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'A') {
        val = 11;
    } else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }
    printf("The card value is :  %i\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

But I got an error : `fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory`

What is the problem ? Please explain complete .

Comment: `iostream.h` is an ***old*** C++ header. Since you are writing C, you can simply remove this line. You'll need to `#include <stdio.h>` for `print`, *etc* .

Comment: Got error : fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory

Comment: I found it in 'Head First C' book , It published 2012 ! Is it old ?

Comment: @JavadMKoushyar: Any [tag:c] reference that tells you to use [tag:c++] headers is not *old* but just plain *wrong*. C and C++ are not the same language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `<iostream.h>` is a (old and deprecated) *C++* header. It's not for use in C programs. Even if the C compiler would find it, it would generate many *many* errors for you.

Comment: Please give me the corrected source.

Comment: @JavadMKoushyar Simply don't include C++ headers in C source files.

Answer (score 3):

Use the header file below

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Ok, I got it and I run my program correct.I have two questions : How can I find C libraries ? Is it possible to do OOP with C ?

Comment: A good source is http://cplusplus.com, it also has a very usable C-library reference.

Comment: @JavadMKoushyar You might want to check [this reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) as well.

Comment: @JavadMKoushyar, just don't let your brain rot too much by C++ stuff. :-) Whenever possible, stick with good old C. If you need a high-level language, well, use a high-level language, like Perl, Python or Ruby. My tuppence.

Comment: I know a little python. Please answer my question : Is it possible to have Object Oriented Programming with C language ? (Y/N)

Comment: Yes it's possible. For instance the Linux kernel implements polymorphism for filesystems "everything is a file" with function pointers.

Comment: Possible, but non-trivial; C doesn't support many OOP concepts directly (polymorphism,  inheritance), so you have to do a *lot* of work that languages like C++ and python do for you.

Comment: If anything is non-trivial, it's debugging C++.